# Read table rows within rowspan

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm looking for a solution to read table rows with jquery but under certain conditions. First column of a table may contain rowspan. I have a button(input) in the last column of the first row of the rowspan collection using which I need to iterate through the rest of rows within this rowspan.

I know how to read table data using class selectors but I do not know how to read only the rows within rowspan. I could not find any useful information anywhere here but if there is already an answer, please provide me with a link. If not, help me to understand the idea.

I tried jquery each(), next(), javascript for loop but none of these led me to anything working.

This where I'm stuck:

```
$("#test tr td:last-child input:submit").on("click", function() {
var rsp = $(this).closest("tr").find(".hostname").attr('rowspan');

if(rsp>0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0,rsp-1).each(function(){
        //read data etc.
        $(this).addClass('sth-class'); //mark a row with a class
    });
}
```

});

Below is a table I'm trying to read.

```
<table id="test" width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="hostname">a1</td>
            <td class="srvc_desc">b1</td>
            <td class="srvc_stat">CRITICAL</td>
            <td class="srvc_last">05-02-2013 00:54:42</td>
            <td class="srvc_dur">0d 3h 53m 12s</td>
            <td class="srvc_att">1/1</td>
            <td class="srvc_excp">Connection refused by host</td>
            <td>
            <input class="send" type="submit" onclientclick="Javascript:return false;" value="Check" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="hostname" rowspan="4">a2</td>
            <td class="srvc_desc">b2</td>
            <td class="srvc_stat">CRITICAL</td>
            <td class="srvc_last">05-02-2013 00:47:02</td>
            <td class="srvc_dur">0d 3h 11m 55s</td>
            <td class="srvc_att">1/1</td>
            <td class="srvc_excp">Connection refused by host</td>
            <td>
            <input class="send" type="submit" onclientclick="Javascript:return false;" value="Check" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="srvc_desc">b3</td>
            <td class="srvc_stat">CRITICAL</td>
            <td class="srvc_last">05-02-2013 00:54:13</td>
            <td class="srvc_dur">0d 3h 49m 55s</td>
            <td class="srvc_att">1/1</td>
            <td class="srvc_excp">Connection refused by host</td>
            <td>
            <input class="send" type="submit" onclientclick="Javascript:return false;" value="Check" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="srvc_desc">b4</td>
            <td class="srvc_stat">CRITICAL</td>
            <td class="srvc_last">05-02-2013 00:54:14</td>
            <td class="srvc_dur">0d 3h 53m 10s</td>
            <td class="srvc_att">3/3</td>
            <td class="srvc_excp">Connection refused by host</td>
            <td>
            <input class="send" type="submit" onclientclick="Javascript:return false;" value="Check" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="srvc_desc">b5</td>
            <td class="srvc_stat">CRITICAL</td>
            <td class="srvc_last">05-02-2013 00:54:42</td>
            <td class="srvc_dur">0d 3h 53m 12s</td>
            <td class="srvc_att">1/1</td>
            <td class="srvc_excp">Connection refused by host</td>
            <td>
            <input class="send" type="submit" onclientclick="Javascript:return false;" value="Check" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="hostname">a3</td>
            <td class="srvc_desc">b6</td>
            <td class="srvc_stat">CRITICAL</td>
            <td class="srvc_last">05-02-2013 00:54:42</td>
            <td class="srvc_dur">0d 3h 53m 12s</td>
            <td class="srvc_att">1/1</td>
            <td class="srvc_excp">Connection refused by host</td>
            <td>
            <input class="send" type="submit" onclientclick="Javascript:return false;" value="Check" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="hostname">a4</td>
            <td class="srvc_desc">b5</td>
            <td class="srvc_stat">CRITICAL</td>
            <td class="srvc_last">05-02-2013 00:54:42</td>
            <td class="srvc_dur">0d 3h 53m 12s</td>
            <td class="srvc_att">1/1</td>
            <td class="srvc_excp">Connection refused by host</td>
            <td>
            <input class="send" type="submit" onclientclick="Javascript:return false;" value="Check" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi, I've seen your code and it does what I already have + highlighting   a row with a rowspan. I'm looking for sth to iterate through row data `if(rsp>0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0,rsp-1).each(function(){
        //read data etc. <--I need this + proper above to let it happen
        $(this).addClass('sth-class'); //mark a row with a class
    });
}`

Comment: I do not need to highlight any rows. In the previous answer I pointed out the place in code and the actual problem. Please have a look at few lines above.

Comment: check this fiddle and open browser console to see data of rows http://jsfiddle.net/QDD5R/4/

Comment: Wow! This is almost sth I'm looking for. Could You please tell me if there is any simple way to read the in-rowspan rows so they are easily accessible like: `var srvc_desc = $(this).closest("tr").find(".srvc_desc").text();`? Thank you

Comment: i think you have to iterate over it too, and if you dont you'll see only the last entry text. Anyways check my answer and if it is ok then mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#test tr td:last-child input:submit").on("click", function() {
var rsp = $(this).closest("tr").find(".hostname").attr('rowspan');

if(rsp>0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0,rsp-1).each(function(){            
        var data = readData($(this));            
        $(this).addClass('sth-class'); //mark a row with a class               
    });
  }
});

function readData(row){
    var data = [];
    row.children("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
        data.push($(this).html());
    });

    return data;
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QDD5R/4/

I hope it helps.

You have to read a row one by through each or any other loop. thanks.

Comment: @abacki.john::: is it ok?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. Your solution gave some insight into idea and allowed me (through some slight modifications) get what I wanted.